# Hive Web Interface not working - HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: hadoop, hive

I tried to use hive HWI to write hive queries on a UI.
As p[er the steps mentioned here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveWebInterface
I set Ant and ran the hive hwi service.

but In browser when i hit mylocaldomain:9999/hwi i got the below error
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /hwi/. Reason:

```
Unable to find a javac compiler;
```

com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre"
Caused by:

Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre"
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:129)

I have checked and changed JAVA_HOME. But its still the same

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy jasper-compiler-jdt.jar into $HIVE_HOME/lib folder. 
i think this jar is missing.

please check this solution

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5132

Comment: This worked form me. Downloaded from a maven site and pasted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting JAVA_HOME to /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre, try following

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_32
```

Also make sure that `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/` contains javac executable

Comment: I have already done that. But still its the same issue. I dont understand where does HWI gets the JAVA_HOME